# Show a region on page if data from json equal to true with Ionic and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm creating an ionic app and there are variables I request from a php page through the Ionic controller. From the variables I get, I have a field called `active` which either be `yes` or `no` for each user after log on.
What I want to achieve is, there is a div on the page called "activediv" and I want that div show only if the variable from the json = yes.

```
.controller('useraccount_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/app_ion/templates/user/user_account.php').success(function(data) {
       $scope.userdata = (data);
   });
}])
```

HTML

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader"> 

<ion-list class="list card" ng-repeat="item in userdata">
   <ion-item href="#/tab/source/{{item.profile_id}}">
 <div class="item item-avatar-big">
<img src="../usr_up_img/{{item.profile_pix}}">
    <h2>{{item.fname}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.country}}</p>
    <p>{{item.curr_city}}</p>
  <div id="activediv">{{item.active}}</div>
  </div>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
```

JSON

```
[{"fname":"Nicholas","country":"India","curr_city":"East Legon","profile_id":"1298","profile_pix":"173333297082.jpg","active":"yes"}]
```

Comment: please include the `json` as well as your whole HTML

Comment: its editted and its included in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="activediv" ng-if ="item.active == 'yes'">{{item.active}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-if

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader"> 

<ion-list class="list card" ng-repeat="item in userdata">
<ion-item href="#/tab/source/{{item.profile_id}}">
<div class="item item-avatar-big">
<img ng-if ="item.profile_pix && item.active =='yes'" src="../usr_up_img/{{item.profile_pix}}">
<h2 ng-if ="item.fname && item.active =='yes'">{{item.fname}}</h2>
<p ng-if ="item.country && item.active =='yes'">{{item.country}}</p>
<p ng-if ="item.curr_city && item.active =='yes'">{{item.curr_city}}</p>
<div id="activediv" ng-if ="item.active =='yes'">{{item.active}}</div>
</div>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: it should show up if the active value is equal to yes alone

Answer (score 0):

[Pravesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840673/show-a-region-on-page-if-data-from-json-equal-to-true-with-ionic-and-angualar/37841043#37841043) answer is good.

You can also use `ng-show` and it will just hide or show your div's content:

```
<div id="activediv" ng-show="item.active == 'yes'">{{item.active}}</div>
```